# Is it possible to populate field with array in Sequelize?

Tags: sql, postgresql, model, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequalize. Tried to figure this out but cant wrap my head around how it works.
So I need to JOIN three tables based on two others

I have my models defined by sequelize-auto. Here is my init-models file

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
var _lesson_students = require("./lesson_students");
var _lesson_teachers = require("./lesson_teachers");
var _lessons = require("./lessons");
var _students = require("./students");
var _teachers = require("./teachers");

function initModels(sequelize) {
  var lesson_students = _lesson_students(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var lesson_teachers = _lesson_teachers(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var lessons = _lessons(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var students = _students(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var teachers = _teachers(sequelize, DataTypes);

  lesson_students.belongsTo(lessons, { as: "lesson", foreignKey: "lesson_id"});
  lessons.hasMany(lesson_students, { as: "lesson_students", foreignKey: "lesson_id"});
  lesson_teachers.belongsTo(lessons, { as: "lesson", foreignKey: "lesson_id"});
  lessons.hasMany(lesson_teachers, { as: "lesson_teachers", foreignKey: "lesson_id"});
  lesson_students.belongsTo(students, { as: "student", foreignKey: "student_id"});
  students.hasMany(lesson_students, { as: "lesson_students", foreignKey: "student_id"});
  lesson_teachers.belongsTo(teachers, { as: "teacher", foreignKey: "teacher_id"});
  teachers.hasMany(lesson_teachers, { as: "lesson_teachers", foreignKey: "teacher_id"});
  // removing unused ids
  lesson_students.removeAttribute('id')
  lesson_teachers.removeAttribute('id')
  
  
  return {
    lesson_students,
    lesson_teachers,
    lessons,
    students,
    teachers,
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

Result eventually should be an object with populated fields.
It should look like something like this

```
{
   id : 9
   date: ‘2019-09-01’ 
   title: ‘Orange’,
   status: 1
   students: [ // populated array of students
      { id: 1,
         name: ‘John’
         visit: true,
   }],
   teachers: [ // populated array of teachers
      { id: 1,
         name: ‘Alice’
      }]
}
```

At the moment i figured out how to get this result

```
{
    id: 10,
    date: '2019-06-24',
    title: 'Brown Color',
    status: 0,
    lesson_teachers: [ [lesson_teachers] ],
    lesson_students: [ [lesson_students] ]
  }
```

by following code

```
resultLessons = await models.lessons.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.lesson_teachers, as: 'lesson_teachers',
    }, {
      model: models.lesson_students, as: 'lesson_students'

    }],
  })
  const lessons = resultLessons.map((lesson) => (lesson.dataValues))
  console.log(lessons)
```

So question is how do I populate [lesson_teachers] and [lesson_students] with actual data? (like method .populate in mongoose)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try changing `lesson.dataValues` to `lesson.toJSON()` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(lessons, null, 2))`

Comment: use association mixins or pass related models to include options